# jQuery each/ajax does not update elements while looping

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, each

I'm trying to update a list after getting some data from an ajax call. It works something like this

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
});

$.ajax(jsonUrl, {
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          $.each(data.list, function(k,v) {
            addOutput("doing something with "+v);
            (...)
          }
        },
        (...)
});

$.ajaxSetup({
  async: true
});
```

addOutput:

```
function addOutput(text, color) {
color = typeof color !== 'undefined' ? color : '#fff';

var date = new Date();
var h = ("0"+date.getHours()).slice(-2);
var m = ("0"+date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
var s = ("0"+date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

var li = "<li style='background-color: "+color+"; padding: 2px; pading-left: 3px;'>"+h+":"+m+":"+s+" - "+text+"</li>"
$("#output_list").prepend(li);
```

}

addOutput(text) is adding a new <li> element to an output console but this is where my problem is. The output console doesn't update immediately instead it updates after jQuery.each is done.

I'm stopping async here because there is another ajax call in the loop to send some requests depending on the list but that's not the problem i guess because i already tested the output without it. So i think it has something to do with jQuery.each?

Update: Added addOutput

Comment: Can't see where the "text" variable is being set here?!

Comment: `async` is an option you can pass through on the `.ajax()` method, removing the need to perform your `$.ajaxSetup()`

Comment: It is just an example to show that addOutput gets some text to display as a list-element in some div. Kind of a console window. Elements are added just fine but my problem is that they are all shown at once AFTER $.each instead while $.each is still running.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm facing the same exact issue right now.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to do this...

```
$.ajax(jsonUrl, {
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          $.each(data.list, function(k,v) {
            addOutput(v); // instead of text, you want to output v. k is index and v is the actual result element
          }
        },
        ...
});
```

**[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/e7e7j/)**

EX:

```
<div class="add"></div>

var result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var index = 0;

$.each(result, function () {
    show();
    debugger;
});

function show() {
    $('.add').append("<h1>" + index + "</h1>");
    index += 1;
}
```

you will find debugger stops while lopping through and adding each element to DOM.

Comment: Maybe i should explain my problem with more details. addOutput is not the problem here. The function is adding elements to the div-window but not while looping through $.each. It is waiting for $.each to finish and then all the elements are added but that is not what i want. I want to have them listed one by one while it is still looping. console.log outputs are working fine btw

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong, success will only be called when the request has the complete response, so it's not an issue, so if you want to cause the impression off a loading list, you'll probably have to do some code with waits for every .each.

Why are you disabling async? This makes the browser do the request without getting the user an stuck screen.

Regards,

Comment: Success is being called and i'm getting into that $.each loop but the elements are not added while looping through. console.log outputs are printed just fine. I'm disabling async because i want to do some more requests in that $.each so i can see whats happening one by one. I'm just building/testing some backend options for me so it's nothing for users to get stuck. Oh and i have some sort of function to cancel the loop later.